# Conjugate of indicator function

Tags: convex-analysis

I know that the conjugate of an indicator function is its support function.
Can someone help determine the the support function of this indicator function?
$I(x) = 1$ if $Ax +b \geq 0$ and it is $0$ otherwise.

Comment: It is not indicator. Indicators have range $\{0,+\infty\}$, not $\{0,1\}$

Comment: I am referring to the following definition:                                           
An indicator function or a characteristic function is a function defined on a set X that indicates membership of an element in a subset A of X, having the value 1 for all elements of A and the value 0 for all elements of X not in A.                                                                              I(x) = 1 if c \in A ,  =0 otherwise

Comment: Your definition does not yield a convex function, so the conjugate of your function is not necessarily a support function.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what is the conjugate of the indicator function I defined above?

Comment: Just use the definition to derive it yourself. What would you use it for though?

Comment: Trying to do so. I need to get the conjugate to use in a nonlinear optimization problem.